# Save Item into database from ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, android-contextmenu

I am stuck with this problem and I can't go any further. So I hope someone can help me here.

**The Problem**
I have a ContextMenu and onLonghold I want to add the item from ListView into the Local Database. But the object is a array like this

```
{name=john,gender=male}
```

---

How I can make it in this way :

```
  object a --> john
  object b --> male
```

So I can add every single String into right colomn in database?

**This What I have until now**

```
 @Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     Object a = adapter.getItem(info.position);
     switch(item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.tilfojToPakke:
         try{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID "+ a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //   dbConnector.insertPakkeList( listview.getSelectedItem().toString(), TAG_fraction_type, TAG_fraction_typetext, TAG_fraction_description, TAG_fraction_extra, TAG_fraction_pictogram);           
         }
         finally
         {

         }
         return true;
     default:
         return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
     }
  }
```

Comment: when you refer "the object is an array like this" is the object an array or a String?

Comment: I spend 2-3 hours on this and I just found the solution, iam sorry for using your time. I had array of hashmap. So all is done now.

Comment: no problem, i didn't spend even 5 mins ;).

Comment: Please delete or answer this question to stop people from looking into it because it looks unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I supposed to use adapter.getItem and so on.